# Cannot access microphone when open link website from facebook

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, facebook-apps, react-toastify

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpSK7.png

```js
const mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices || (navigator as any).webkitMediaDevices || (navigator as any).mozMediaDevices ||
    (navigator as any).msMediaDevices;
if (mediaDevices) {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
                // next todo
            })
    .catch((error: any) => {
        onStartRecording(false);
        toast.error("Cannot access microphone");
    });
```

I use this code, it work in gg, tele, edge ... but when I open website from facebook after start record show Cannot access microphone

I want record audio when open website from facebook

Comment: Is the behaviour the same if you add an interaction? i.e. if you have a button that starts off the whole process. Also, is it just the Facebook app? and is the behaviour the same across Android / iOS?

Comment: i click in a post facebook url my website, getUserMedia not working in webview facbook